# Append not appending

Tags: python, append

I'm creating a wordsearch in python and it's mostly going well.

Unfortunatley i have run into an issue with .append()

When adding the location of matching letters to a list, nothing happens:

```
final_result = []
if (length == len(word)):
    print(result_location) # prints: [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]
    final_result.append(result_location)
    print(final_result) # prints: [[], []]
```

I'm a bit confused by this; as far as i know this is the correct way to add to a list.

Also if I create a test list `test = [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]`
and add it in the exact same way, it works

```
final_result = []
test = [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]
if (length == len(word)):
    final_result.append(test)
    print(final_result) # prints: [[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]]
```

but if I set test = result_location and append with test it doesn't work despite the origional list and the list after the above operation being identical

At a loss and any help would be appreciated

edit:
been asked to post a bit more of the code

```
final_result = []
puzzle = ['RUNAROUNDDL', 'RUNAROUNDDL', 'ZYUWSWEDZYA', 
'AKOTCONVOYV',
           'LSBOSEVRUCI', 'BOBLLCGLPBD', 'LKTEENAGEDL', 
 'ISTREWZLCGY',
           'AURAPLEBAYG', 'RDATYTBIWRA', 'TEYEMROFINU']
word = "around"
result_location = []



def check_horizontal(puzzle, word):
    word = word.upper()
    test = [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8)]

    # for loop through puzzle (columns)
    for i in range(0, len(puzzle), 1):
        count = 0
        success_count = 0

        # for loop through columns (rows)
        for j in range(0, len(puzzle[0]), 1):

            # tests test letter against puzzle
            if puzzle[i][j] == word[count]:
                success_count += 1
                count += 1
                result_location.append(tuple([i, j]))

            # resets counter and clears list of results on negative
            elif puzzle[i][j] != word[count]:
                count = 0
                success_count = 0
                result_location.clear()
        
            # returns tuple on success
            # honestly baffled why append wont append result_location
            if success_count == len(word):
                print (result_location)
            
                final_result.append(result_location)
                result_location.clear()
                count = 0

    print(final_result)

    check_horizontal(puzzle, word)
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign something to `test` by writing `test ==`?

Comment: no only a single `=`

Comment: Post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code in your post doesn't tell the whole story.

Comment: You wrote "if I set `test == result_location`", that's not a single `=`.

Comment: You do append a list. But then you clear that list. It's still appended but it's empty.

Comment: my mistake. fixed

Comment: Help us help you. Your code is neither minimal nor reproducable.

Comment: BTW you can use the question editor to indent everything by 4 spaces so that we don't have to imagine it. Select the code and press the {} button.

Comment: I append final_result with result_location `final_result.append(result_location)` and then clear result_location after

Comment: Exactly. And then the `result_location` list which was appended to `final_result` is empty. But `append` did append.

Comment: Do you have *result_location = final_result* somewhere in your code? Because if you do, that will explain it

Comment: when I appended to `final_result`, `result_location = [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8)]` 
to my knowledge that should add to `final_result` and the clear in the next line should not affect it

Comment: Code should now run when copy pasted and should be reproducable